# Xamarin iOS Code Signing Option in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.ios, code-signing

in xCode we have an option that let's us set Code Signing Identity to 'Don't Code Sign', but i couldn't find that option in xamarin ios, both in visual studio and Xamarin Studio.

i think that option is not available in Xamarin.is there any workaround so we can let that happen while building ios projects. i want to test my app on a jail broken device.
and with out any developer account i can't generate ipa files. i tried many ways but couldn't find any solution.

is there anyway to solve this issue without buying developer id from Apple ?

Comment: If you want to deploy to a device you must have a paid developer account.

Comment: that's not completely true, if your device has been jail broken , and set Code Signing Identity to 'Don't Code Sign' in xCode, you can run your project in your device.
but the mentioned option is not available in xamarin ios.